# Create a new page for different php ORDER BY statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a PHP script that outputs a list of reviews in a table and orders them by the date they were submitted - (similar to have Trip Advisor ratings work).

Below I have included how the table heading are set out:

NAME || DATE || REVIEW || RATING

Below I have listed the code:

```
//run a query to find all the fields in the review table that belong to the specific hall, using the id in the url ($current_id)
if ($r = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE hall_id = :current_id ORDER BY overall DESC")) {
    //bind the parameters used in the above query using the 'current_id' variable
    $r->bindParam(':current_id', $current_id);
    //Execute the prepared query
    $r->execute(); 

        //search review table for all fields and save them in $review
        $reviewtemp = $r->fetchAll();
       foreach( $reviewtemp as $review) { ...
```

`ORDER BY date DESC` orders the reviews by the date. However, when the user clicks on the 'RATING' header in the table, I need the reviews to be ordered by the highest rating (which is a number). So `ORDER BY date DESC` would change into `ORDER BY rating DESC`.

I'm unsure whether I have to create an entire new page (and simply change 1 word of my php script) to do this, or if there is a more simple and efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't make whole new page, I would say have a variable that you can change that you would use in the order by in your query.

```
$orderby = 'rating';
```

And then your query would have "`ORDER BY $orderby DESC`"

**EDIT**

If you make the date header a link to "yourscript.php?orderby=date", you could have something like this on "yourscript.php"

```
switch($_GET['orderby']){
    case 'date':
        $orderby = 'date';
        break;
    default :
        $orderby = 'rating';
        break;
}
```

Comment: So when I click on the date heading in the table - `<td class="table-head">Date</td>` I need the variable $orderby to contain the word 'date' and the page to refresh? How would I do this?  @nickbwatson

Comment: One way to accomplish this would be to simply make the Date a link to "yourscript.php?orderby=date", I'll edit my answer so you can see

Comment: the reason I used a switch is because it'll allow you to add other ways to sort your data.  You COULD just scrap that whole switch and just say `$orderby = $_GET['orderby'];` however this will leave you vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I found this solution a couple of days ago, many thanks for completing the question though

Answer (score 0):

Up to you, but when I do this I use [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Take a look, it lets you display the results and clicking on the headers reorders on the fly, no new queries. It also lets you sort by more than one column by holding shift.

I whipped up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8ThK/) for you to check out.

```
http://tablesorter.com
```

Comment: it appears that doesn't work when the table is populated with different data each time using a php script @user3495831

Comment: I'm a little confused, are the columns of your table changing?

Comment: yes, the table is populated with data from a database using php echos

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working for you. I have many pages that generate data dynamically using php to piece together the table then echo-ing it to the screen and tablesorter works great for me. Could be the table isn't formatted correctly (with <thead>) or could be the jquery isn't correct. Good luck.