# change session variable when clicking on link

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, session

This is an extension of the question here - [Create a new page for different php ORDER BY statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22868745/2796717)

I basically need to change a session variable and refresh the page at the same time using php (I think).

I.e. When I click `<a href="#">Sort by date<a>` on my page the following things happen:

- `$_SESSION['orderby']; = 'date';`
- Page refreshes

The session variable will then be changed and used later in my code.

I may need to use javascript? I'm not really sure, how would I do this?

EDIT

I do NOT want/need to be redirected to another page, the page just needs to be refreshed. Basically I need to click on a link (or button) and a php variable needs to be changed.

AJAX maybe?

Answer (score 1):

What you would be able to do, is appending a `GET`-value to the URL and fetch that with PHP.

For instance:

```
<!-- HTML -->
Sort by <a href='?sort=date'>date</a>

// PHP:
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $_SESSION['orderby'] = $_GET['sort'];
}
```

Additionally you can check if the `GET`-value is in a given array (to avoid errors from url-manipulation):

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sorts = array('date', 'ranking', 'page'); // ...
    $_SESSION['orderby'] = (in_array($_GET['sort'], $sorts) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'STANDARD SORT');
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to url to change when the link is clicked. I simple need the page to refresh and the session variable to be changed. with the above code when the link is clicked the url changes from ...halls.php?id=1 to ...halls.php?sort=date which obviously displays the page incorrectly? @Padarom

Answer (score 0):

use ajax send your var to php file to update session

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'date.php',
      data: {'date':date},
      success: function(result) {
       console.log(result)
      } 
    });
```

date.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['date'])){
      $_SESSION['date'] = $_POST['date'];
      echo 'Date set to: '.$_SESSION['date'];
      }
    }
```